# Removing a character from a list in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

For example

I have a file `testing.txt` that reads

```
read 3 4
```

Consider

```
(define file(open-input file "testing.txt"))
```

I want to remove the `r` in `read` instead of the whole word, I want to update file without the first character `r`, I know I can not use this using `cdr file` because it erases the word `read`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of hints for your homework. This will return a list, with each line of the file as a string in the list:

```
(define lines (file->lines "testing.txt"))
```

This procedure will write an input `text` to a file in the given `path`, overwriting the contents of the file:

```
(define (write-to-a-file path txt)
  (call-with-output-file path
    (lambda (output-port)
      (display txt output-port))
    #:exists 'replace))
```

You can use the procedures `string->list`, `list->string` (see the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html)), `car` and `cdr` to manipulate the list returned by `file->lines`, and write the resulting text using `write-to-a-file`. Now you have all you need to solve the problem by yourself.